# unhandled Query implementation org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQuery

Tags: codeigniter

I tried to create RestTemplate Bean with ElasticSearchClient insed of RestHighLevelClient getting this error. Code was compiled and I am to run th application as well. While fetching the data it is happening.

Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
.withQuery(booleanQueryBuilder)
.withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, searchAddressRequest.getMaxRecordsRequested()))
.build();

```
    return elasticsearchOperations.search(query, SomeIndex.class);
```

**I am using springboot 2.7.8**

@Bean
public ElasticsearchTemplate getElasticsearchTemplate(
@Qualifier ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient, AddressMappingEsConverter addressMappingEsConverter) {
return new ElasticsearchTemplate(elasticsearchClient, addressMappingEsConverter);
}

Comment: Why is this tagged with `codeigniter`?